# Extension method for DropDownList causing error

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have an extension method for `DropDownList` that's throwing `Extension method can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes` on the keyword `this`. I'm not quite sure why though since I've seen plenty of examples with extension methods on `DropDownList`

```
public static class DropDownListExtensions {
    public static void populateDropDownList(this DropDownList source, Action delegateAction) {
        source.DataValueField = "Key";
        source.DataTextField = "Value";
        source.DataSource = delegateAction;
        source.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly your `DropDownListExtensions` class declared as nested of some other class. Move it to namespace level.